# How to create a chart in Kibana from a set number

Tags: elastic-stack

I have a task that sends to Kibana a number of files it's supposed to run, then it sends an event for each file that finishes. How can I configure my Kibana to give me a pie chart of remaining files from finished files? (If it's impossible to do with a pie chart I'd like to hear about other charts to do that with)

Ideally if for example I have 20 files and 5 finished I want my pie to be 3 quarters of one color (waiting files) and 1 quarter another color (finished files).

Comment: How're you identifying whether it's a **finished** file or not?

Comment: The log sends an event with a field containing the finished file name.

Comment: If you could show a *snapshot* of an event in *Kibana*?

Answer (score 0):

If you're to use the *pie* chart, you might have to differentiate the file whether it's a finished one or a waiting one by using **filter** aggregation. You can have a look at [this](https://www.timroes.de/2015/02/07/kibana-4-tutorial-part-3-visualize/#filters), for more about using the *filter*.

So in your case, let's assume if you have a field called **status** which has distinct values as `waiting` and `finished`. What you can do is to have two **filters** containing:

```
filter 1
status:'waiting'

filter 2
status:'finished'
```

So the above would actually split your *pie chart* into two sections where one containing the `waiting` events and the other containing `finished` events with two different colors. This is just a thought so that you could reproduce. Hope it helps!

Comment: Problem is I don't get an event for each waiting file. Only an event at the beginning of the log telling me how many files there are. Then each "finished" event should subtract 1 from the waiting files but I don't know if there's a way to do that.